# How to create Win10 USB boot stick with UEFI support?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb

I want to install Windows 10 via USB. I also want to use UEFI.

I downloaded this iso https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO

As I want to use UEFI, I have to partition my USB stick with FAT32, which comes with a max-size for files to 4GB. However, the file "install.wim" from that Windows 10 iso is 5.2 GB, so it cannot be copied to the USB stick.

Is there another win 10 image that I perhaps can use? Or is there any other way around it beside installing it to a DVD?

I am a bit surprised by this, because I thought DVD's are outdated (Many new Laptop's don't even have DVD drives installed) and also, I found many instructions online how to create the Win10 Boot USB and they all state to format FAT32?

Comment: The computer on or using which you wish to create Bootable USB, is it running Windows, Linux or Mac? If Windows simply use Rufus. https://rufus.ie/en/ It will take care of everything including UEFI NTFS Driver

Comment: Alternatively use Ventoy for Windows or Linux https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html

Comment: @patkim I am using Linux, just trying out ventoy. Sounds very exciting, I hope it will work. Let you know in a while, currently coping iso files

Comment: Note that Ventoy will create a small FAT partition with its own bootloader. It will also create an exFAT partition on the pendrive where you need to copy the ISO file as-is (without expanding/extracting)

Comment: @patkim yes, currently coping the win iso file directly to the exFAT. The FAT partition is only 32MB, so can't store anything there anyway. Next I will also copy the Ubuntu iso also to exFAT. If this works, then it will make installations with Win/Linux on new machines so much easier for me!

Comment: The FAT partition is the UEFI boot partition only. It contains bootloader and exFAT driver. UEFI will boot from it and mount the exFAT partition and show you all ISO's list to choose from at the boot screen.

Comment: @patkim thank you, that worked for me. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: I have added a detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are several ways on Linux, the easiest I find is using a multi-ISO boot tool called Ventoy which is available for Windows as well as Linux.

It can be downloaded from here  https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy/releases

On Linux extract the tar.gz file to a directory.

[image]

Plug in a pen drive at least 8GB for Windows ISO, 16 GB for more

On typical x64 systems run the script `VentoyGUI.x86_64` in terminal. However Ventoy2Disk.sh has several command line options. Need to run it as superuser.
Ventoy will show the GUI interface and the mounted pendrive device as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

Click Install

Ventoy will format the device and create two partitions on it. One is a 32MB FAT partition which is the UEFI bootloader and another larger exFAT partition to store the ISO files. This ensures UEFI support as well as support for larger ISO’s > 4GB

[image]

Ventoy will confirm the status of this operation.

[image]

Now if not already mounted, mount the exFAT partition and copy all bootable ISO’s on it at root level directly as-is without any extraction.

[image]

Boot your system in UEFI mode (preferably secure boot disabled) and select Pendrive smaller FAT partition as boot device.

Ventoy will boot thru its bootloader, mount the exFAT partition and show you list of ISO’s to choose from.

[image]

Upon selection, booting will start, as long as ISO is properly UEFI bootable.

The list of supported bootable ISO files tested on Ventoy is here https://www.ventoy.net/en/isolist.html

More on Ventoy support on Secure Boot & related recommended procedure is documented here https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_secure.html