# How to create a backup for a bootable usb

Tags: linux, usb, backup, bootable-media

I have a good usb I use to test and run linux distros. My problem is that I can only ever install one at a time and if i want to test another one I need to delete everything I have. So I tried to find an application (for windows but linux would work as well) which can create a backup of my usb let me restore it. Are there any Options that work and preferably don't look like viruses?

The only one I found so far was ImgBurn and when I tried to load the backup my system didn't work anymore.

Edit: I want to have persistent storage on the usb.

Comment: USB Keys are inexpensive. I have several. I copy what I need from any given USB Key to my computer and re-use it

Comment: I use Image USB by Passmark https://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html Alternatively use Ventoy see here https://superuser.com/questions/1756553/how-to-create-win10-usb-boot-stick-with-uefi-support/1758255#1758255

Answer (score 4):

Why backup when you can have *ONE* bootable USB stick that can install/boot *MANY* operating systems?

There are several apps that will make bootable USB drives with multiple bootable operating systems installers and liveCDs.

- [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)
- [XBoot](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/XBoot.shtml)
- [MultiBootUSB](https://github.com/mbusb/multibootusb/releases)
- [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/)
- probably more, google for them

Then boot off that bootable USB and select the image you want to boot.

Comment: I personally find Ventoy much more convenient and reliable than YUMI.

Comment: Can you use these with persistancy and not just live isos? 
Sorry for not mentioning that beforehand.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Lucky_Star Honestly, I dont remember...  I used Yumi, but only to install OSs or run some bootable utilities.  However, there is no harm in trying... or maybe theres documentation on the websites that says if it will work.

Comment: @Lucky_Star I just looked at the website for YUMI and it supports persistance.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of good software that can do this for you.

I recommend using `Veeam backup & replication` to backup your drive and then restore it using Veeam whenever you want.